# Remove a combination of characters in a string python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, string

Regex newbie alert please be gentle. I am having strings like:

```
sent = 'The type of vehicle FRFR7800 is the fastest'
```

I want to remove the duplicate occurence of the substring 'FR'. So the string should be:

```
sent = 'The type of vehicle FR7800 is the fastest'.
```

I think I have spent more than 2 hours reading/trying the tutorial of [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) and the more pythonic way of [groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and I really can't figure it out. I also searched the similar questions and most of the results are covering the case when there are I repeated same characters e.g. having strings like 'dddddaaaaaggggg' etc. A couple of them helped but I ended up deleting the all occurences of 'FR'.

For example I tried:

```
sent = re.sub(r'FC{1}', '', sent)
sent = re.sub(r'FC|', '', sent)
```

These removed completely the occurence of 'FR'. When I changed it to:

```
sent = re.sub(r'FC{2}', '', sent)
```

Nothing happened, the string remained having the 'FR' occurence repeated.

Can somebody help me with or give me a hint ?

Comment: @VishalSingh You're hardcoded `FR` as the substring, which I doubt is what the OP wants here.

Comment: fixed it @TimBiegeleisen https://regex101.com/r/Jg99O9/1

Comment: @Vishal Singh thank you for the answer. I have also found that I don't know how to syntax it in python. I tried it and removed all occurences. I tried: 
sent = re.sub(r'(\w{2})\1', '', sent)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re

sent = "The type of vehicle FRFR7800 is the fastest"
regex = r"(\w{2})\1"

print(re.sub(regex, r"\g<1>", sent))
```

Comment: thank you! This solved it. Didn't realise that in the replace string parameter ( r"\g<1>" ) I could use a regular expression too.

Comment: This is nice, but be careful that you really understand the text you will work on since it replaces all pairs like this and these pair exist in English. ie. see results with `"The papal cocoa-puff dispenser of hippopotamus-shaped vehicle FRFR7800 is in crisis"`